# Disable eslint for all files but js files?

Tags: javascript, eslint

Right now it's giving error that .png and .less files aren't valid, everything is invalid.

I want eslint to only look at .js and .jsx files.

I don't see any way to do that.

I did find eslintignore which is not the best way to do things.

I don't want to maintain a list of files to ignore.

Whitelist approach please.

Comment: How are you running eslint?

Comment: in vscode and gulp

Comment: i was hoping there would be something i could put in .eslintrc

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the property "overrides" on your .eslintrc file to include only the files/file types you want:

```
{
    "overrides": [
        {
            "files": [ "src/**/*.js", "src/**/*.jsx" ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Docs: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#example-configuration

Comment: did that and it still tries to lint .png etc. WHen I add pngs to the .eslintignore, it stops but there should be a better way

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is no way to configure it other than the arguments for the CLI

If you are running it through gulp, first pipe the src like

```
src(['**/*.js', '**/*.jsx'])
        .pipe(eslint())
...
```

If you would rather do it via npm command, you can create a script in your package.json like so:

```
"scripts": {
  ...
  "eslint": "eslint **/*.js **/*.jsx",
```

Then invoke it with `npm run eslint`